# Binary tree for 2 elements

Tags: algorithms

I want to understand Binary Search for 2 element list made of 1,2. I draw a tree as below. Is it correct?

[image]

If I want to search for an element 2, it will make 2 comparisons. If I want to search for an element 22, it will also make 2 comparisons. But according to formula Θ(lg n), with n=2, it should make only one comparison in worst case. I'm not able to connect these 2 facts. Please help me.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask this question on Comp Sci SO

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the binary tree is correct in that the right node is greater than the parent node, but it is not optimal because the search tree will not be balanced. The fact that the root node is 1 will mean that for the first comparison, the search algorithm will navigate right.

What is happening is the binary search tree in your example is acting as a linked list with a time complexity of Θ(n) instead.

This can been seen in the "Searching" here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/trees.html